# How do I ask password by GUI prompt while using sudo in script?

Tags: shell-script, sudo, password, prompt, gui

I use Trisquel GNU/Linux with GNOME Flashback Desktop Environment. I need a GUI password prompt for user for executing command with `sudo` in script. Example consider following script:

```
zenity --question --text="Do you want to install this package?"
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then sudo apt-get install package
else zenity --warning
fi
```

Which is to be executed following way (Run) i.e not inside terminal:

[image: screen-shot]

So, It is needed to ask for password in order to run command with `sudo` otherwise it fails to do a job.

Therefore, How do I ask password by GUI prompt?

Comment: A oneliner could do it: `echo $(zenity --password --title="Enter sudo password") | sudo -S [your command]`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can ask password by means of GUI prompt with the help of **`-A, --askpass`** options for `sudo`.

From the `sudo` manpage:

```
-A, --askpass
                 Normally, if sudo requires a password, it will read it from the user's terminal.  If the -A
                 (askpass) option is specified, a (possibly graphical) helper program is executed to read the user's
                 password and output the password to the standard output.  If the SUDO_ASKPASS environment variable
                 is set, it specifies the path to the helper program.  Otherwise, if sudo.conf(5) contains a line
                 specifying the askpass program, that value will be used.  For example:

                     # Path to askpass helper program
                     Path askpass /usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass

                 If no askpass program is available, sudo will exit with an error.
```

So, you can graphical helper program such as `ssh-askpass` which **prompts a user for a pass-phrase** using GNOME:

```
$ which ssh-askpass
/usr/bin/ssh-askpass
```

**So, Add the following line to `/etc/sudo.conf`:**

```
# Path to askpass helper program
Path askpass /usr/bin/ssh-askpass
```

And you will find GUI password prompt:

[image: screen-shot1]

You can also user other program like `zenity` for that. Example I use following:

```
$ cat /etc/sudo.conf
# Path to askpass helper program
Path askpass /usr/local/bin/zenity_passphrase
```

Where `zenity_passphrase` is a custom script [set](https://askubuntu.com/q/465109/256099) to be used directly as command:

```
$ cat $(which zenity_passphrase)
#!/bin/bash
zenity --password --title="sudo password prompt" --timeout=10
```

Which works like:

[image: screen-shot2]

---

Note:

- You can also use **`gksudo`** (GTK+ frontend for su and sudo) instead of `sudo` in the script which asks with GUI prompt (`gksu` and `gksudo` are obsolete and abandoned in 2019-2020):

  [image: screen-shot3]
- You can also use **`pkexec`** ([polkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit) application) with some (for others it needs to be configure) applications/commands:

  [image: screen-shot]

Comment: When using pkexec, for example `pkexec leafpad`, it gives `Cannot open display:` after entering the password. Is there any aditional configuration needed?

Comment: Try `DISPLAY=:0 pkexec leafpad`

Comment: Still not working, the same message `Cannot open display:` appears

Comment: `gksu` and `gksudo` is dead, abandoned in 2019 or before that.

Comment: For KDE (on Manjaro) you also can use `/usr/lib/ssh/ssh-askpass` (package: x11-ssh-askpass) or `/usr/bin/qt4-ssh-askpass` (package:  openssh-askpass)

Comment: @Pandya, use `pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY leafpad`